# Inner join base on specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 3 tables Brand,Product and BrandProduct respectively.Table has following structure.

```
Brand : id,BrandName
Product : id,ProductName
BrandProduct :id,Brandid,Productid,Prize,RetailerName
```

I want to display the name of product,prize and retailername.This is my query.

```
select ProductName,Prize,RetailerName from BrandProduct BP
inner join Product P
on P.id = BP.Productid
```

When user select Brand,only that's brand record should come.So I changed a query.It is working properly

```
  create proc_sample
   @Brandid int = null
   as
   begin
    select ProductName,Prize,RetailerName from BrandProduct BP
    inner join Product P
    on P.id = BP.Productid
    inner join Brand B
    on B.id = BP.Brandid
    where (@Brandid is null or BP.Brandid= @Brandid)
   End
```

When user will not select brand,join of Brand should not come.Any Idea?I know Dynamic sql come into picture.Any alternative to dynamic sql

Comment: try to tag your question properly, that will help reaching the right audience

Comment: Did you mean `left join Brand B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to join Brand table, because BrandProduct table contains BrandId.

```
select ProductName,Prize,RetailerName from BrandProduct BP
inner join Product P
on P.id = BP.Productid
where (@Brandid is null or BP.Brandid = @Brandid)
```